# Use a 1/8 inch mesh to keep out roaches?

Tags: fireplace, pest-control, chimney

Can I put a 1/8th inch mesh over the unused chimney and chimney cap to keep roaches and other large insects from entering?

Somehow a few get every once in a while, and I find them on the bench or base, or dying on the floor near it.

The damper is closed and we don't intend on using this fireplace, but want to account for unplanned use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem doing what you want to do. Get a mesh that you can bend with a little bit of force and make it a little smaller so it stays in place over the chimney. I put a brick on top of mine because raccoons were still getting in. Don't be surprised if a few little critters still get in every once in a while... that's why they call them pests.

Comment: Agree there pests. :) Just one part of the strategy. Thanks